# Woocommerce Product Variation - Add Price Logic

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I have an issue when I tried to add more than 300 variations on thousands of products on my website. There are two many of them so that it is not possible to add variations manually. Actually, it could be done by logic, but I don't know how to add logic to the variation part. If you could tell me which plugin works or how to write php logic code for this, I'll be very appreciated!

Here's my logic example:

Suppose I have a computer whose base price is 1000$. Then I have an option of LED stripe types and an option for number of LED stripe types. Each type has its own price. So the total price will be 1000 + 5(number of stripes) * 2(price for yellow type) = 1010$.

I tried to write python script code to add variations in CSV file and import CSV variations. But Woocommerce seems can't handle with new variations that have no IDs. So I'm looking for logic code or a workable plugin.

Comment: Is Extra Product Options (Product Addons) for WooCommerce (https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/woo-extra-product-options/) what you're looking for? There is a demo shop linked in the description.

Comment: Adding to my last comment, I think that the variable pricing is a premium feature in the mentioned plugin.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think that plugin works. I tried a similar plugin before. They can only add a numerical or percentage on price. But I need to add based on number and type chosen. This logic is not supported.